# How to answer "Have you ever been terminated?"

Tags: interviewing, job-search, hiring-process, united-states, human-resources

I'm filling out a job application that asks the question "Have you ever been terminated or asked to resign from a position in the past?"

I did get fired from a job back in 1998. It was my first high-profile tech job after I graduated high school, and I was still very much a smug kid with a crappy work ethic. I antagonized my boss whom I despised, and I naively believed that finding work was pitifully easy since this was the height of the dot-com bubble at the time.

I won't even try to spin this as "not my fault" because it totally was.  I'm perfectly comfortable owning up to the mistakes I made because that was over 20 years ago and I was a literal teenager at the time. I've done a lot of growing up since then and I'm a different person now.

On the one hand, I want to be honest and forthright on a job application. On the other hand, HR departments often use this question to immediately reject potential applicants without consideration of the reasons.

I've had a long and successful career since then and I don't feel that being fired an entire lifetime ago is relevant to the position I'm applying for now. I'd be fine with engaging the discussion in an interview if asked, but there is no room in a 400 character text box for that kind of nuance.  The job I got fired from isn't on my resume because it was so long ago, and the company doesn't even exist anymore.

I'm looking for work because I've recently been laid off from a job I've had for 10 years due to an acquisition and workforce reduction. It was made clear to me by my former boss and my termination paperwork that the layoff is in no way related to performance or disciplinary reasons. In fact, my most recent performance review was positively stellar. But a layoff is already a small hill I have to climb and I don't want to further taint an application to a potential employer with something that shouldn't even matter anymore.

Is there an acceptable expiration date on such questions? Will I be branded a liar if I answer no?

If I answer yes, how could I explain it succinctly, and do HR departments typically consider those explanations when screening applicants?

Comment: You gave us two paragraphs describing why you were fired, which is only ~630 characters. I was able to pare that down and add a sentence or two about growing up and receiving a stellar performance review at your 10-year job, and still came in under 400 characters. If you decided to mention this, you should be able to write up something concise for that text box.

Comment: Depending on your location, a "redundancy" is quite different to "being terminated"

Comment: @Criggie; I don't understand what you mean by "redundancy"

Comment: @WesSayeed "terminated" means the employer doesn't want you in the job any more.  "redundant" means the job position itself is gone.  In the former its all about the person, and in the latter its nothing to do with the person so is less bad.

Comment: @Criggie; Ah I see. I'm in the US (which I failed to mention in my post), and we call that a layoff or a "workforce reduction". But no, I was fired/sacked/whatever 20 years ago on account of being an insufferable, entitled jerk who showed up late all the time and only did the work I felt like doing. My most recent job was a layoff. There is a legal distinction between the two.

Comment: I really hope you're not posting this question under your real name.

Comment: It is easier to explain you were fired for bad work ethic 20 years ago, than to explain that you were fired recently for lying on a job application...

Comment: Pretty sure it would be a hassle to deal with an automated system that excludes anyone who answers "yes" to that question. The only acceptable case to do so would be if the position is an internship or entry-level (person got fired from the first job and is very inexperienced).  Which is not your case. People with several years in the marketplace are likely to have one or more terminations in their CVs. Also, not every company gets hundreds of applicants for every position.

Comment: To be honest (ha!), in your position I would lie. The odds are in your favour here.

Answer (score 83):

It would be understandable to say no, because it's unlikely anyone would put in the effort to verify you were fired over 20 years ago from a non-existent company, especially if that job is not in your resume.

The problem with saying "no" is that it is not the truth. And not telling the truth seems to bother you, which is not an uncommon response.

This is a personal ethical choice to be sure, but you'll also have to carry around the worry, irrational or not, that someone someday will find out.

If this was a question about work history, I would definitely omit that job since it was so long ago, but that's not what the question is asking.

There's no way to say for sure what any particular company's policy is with a question like that. In my experience companies usually take context into consideration. The fact that they provide 400 words for this (as opposed to a simple checkbox) does seem to indicate they are doing so. The company would likely not go through the trouble of handling an application if they blindly rejected anyone who had been terminated.

I would say yes, and also briefly explain that it was 20 years ago, and served as a wake-up call and important learning lesson. You can turn this into a positive.

A company who would reject you based on that answer (or outsource that rejection power to an automated process) is probably not one you'd want to work for.

Comment: My only reservation about your answer is the last paragraph. Often times employers go through 3rd parties to harvest applications and pre-screen candidates. This job appears on the company's own web site, but the Apply Now button links to a 3rd party HR firm with this company's branding. If the 3rd party system is set up to auto-reject a candidate based on certain checkboxes being checked, I don't think it says anything about the company one way or the other. I just want my application rejected by a human if that is to be the case, not a machine.

Comment: And even within a company, the junior HR person who sticks to their checkboxes is not necessarily anyone you would interact with later

Comment: "Yes, once back when I was a stupid teenager." – spoken by someone with 20+ years of professional experience, the interviewer may just check "no" on their form if they make the call that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @WesSayeed understandable -- a lot of times however, you get jobs through referrals and networking, not through application harvesters. With pre-screened processes you can get flagged for many things, including not having the right acronyms on your resume.

Comment: "*In my experience companies usually take context into consideration*" Are you saying that in your experience, hiring managers **DO** actually read and consider the explanation you provide?

Comment: @WesSayeed I can't speak for automated processes, but in interviews I'm always asked why I left my my previous job, which is a standard interview question. Typically hiring managers are far more interested in what you can do for them in the future, especially given your skills and your most recent work.

Comment: @WesSayeed: A company who employs a third party recruiter, but does not vet the recruiter's recruitment practices (dismissing applications based on an unelaborated answer); is similarly disinterested in its employees as a company who does the recruiting themselves and dismisses your application based on that one answer. In all cases, the recruitment process is the responsibility of the company - it's their choice to outsource it, it's their choice to choose how to approach it. A bad recruitment process always reflects badly on the company - barring exceptional HR employee misbehavior.

Comment: @WesSayeed - Just remember, if a machine does reject your application based on a checkbox, a human chose to put that machine there. 
That human likely either knew the risks of losing a potentially good candidate, or would have rejected on the checkbox alone themselves. They could also have been negligent, or ignorant, and not truly considered the consequences.
Either way, if a machine made the choice to reject your application, a human made the choice to let the machine decide.

Comment: @WesSayeed irrespective of the company's intentions, with this process in place you would know that some of your future colleagues would be the second-best people for their jobs because the best candidate got pre-screened out on some trivial matter, and some would be more comfortable than average with lying. This will affect the workplace you are considering entering, as will the decisionmaking that has allowed the process to work this way as Azrantha has highlighted.

Comment: The first paragraph might not be true.  Equifax (and similar brokers), for example, keeps track of employment history records it has, even dating back decades, and that data won't always show up in a credit report or place you can access it, but your potential employer might be able to find out.

Comment: @WBT good point, thank you. Another reason to give a straight answer.

Comment: I'd worry a bit about saying "20 years ago" because it opens the door for age discrimination, simply by revealing you have at least 20 years of employment history. Maybe the company prefers to hire 20-somethings who will work themselves to death without asking for much salary. They won't *ask* you your age, because that makes it obvious they will consider illegally discriminating. But if you volunteer it, it's very hard to tell if that influenced their decision. Instead I'd say, "once, back when I was a teenager".

Comment: @amalloy that's a very good point. Saying only "teenager" makes the job and firing even less relevant.

Answer (score 47):

> I did get fired from a job back in 1998... I've recently been laid off
>   from a job I've had for 10 years
>
> How to answer the question: "Have you ever been terminated or asked to
>   resign from a position in the past?"

Thus, the correct answer to the question is "Yes. I was fired once over 20 years ago while still a teenager. And I was recently laid off as a result of an acquisition."

You could then go on to explain how you have grown since your early years. Most interviewers will understand that.

Comment: The "once, 20 years ago" part really helps. I don't think any sane hiring manager would require more explanation than that. It's like saying "yes, I did crazy things in college" or "I, too, was a teenager many years ago".

Comment: Why not use this same approach to answer 'yes' but refer to the recent layoff and leave off the job from 20 years ago, especially since it isn't in the work history.  How tight is that walking the ethical tightrope?

Comment: Perhaps "as a result of an acquisition" could be better than "after an acquisition". The point is to say (assuming it's true) that the acquisition was the *only* reason for the layoff.

Comment: It isn't necessary to mention being laid off in the answer.  Being laid off isn't being fired, nor is it being asked to resign.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I don't agree with that, and I don't think it's what the question is really asking.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, sure, one could say that every single time the OP has switched jobs, it was a termination.  But one would think that that's covered in the employment history.

Comment: We could stop going around in circles here if you were to clearly state what you think "terminated" means.

Answer (score 16):

It’s ethical to be concerned about how to answer it and honestly my first thought was no one will fault you on principle even if it were provable.  But as I thought about it, it occurred to me that 400 characters may be the perfect space.  Nuance is not for the application process.  If you had eight paragraphs to explain, they’d skip you before you reached your conclusion.  Application is about not getting weeded out and making an impression.  You might even do yourself a favor by answering affirmatively.

By analogy, say you go out for pizza.  The order is taken, completed in reasonable time and a good pizza overall.  Does that experience stand out over the last dozen times you’ve had pizza?  If they burned your pizza, apologized, got your drinks and an appetizer while they did it right and didn’t charge you, are they a bad restaurant or a great one?

> Have you ever been terminated or asked to resign from a position in the past?
>
> Yes, once as a teen--and it was one of the single most valuable
>   lessons of my (early?) career.  I’ve since learned my confidence was
>   not misplaced, but how I interacted with others was forever shaped for
>   the better on that day.

Ultimately, anything is a gamble.  A simple “no” is safe, but leaves you no more intriguing than the other dozen applicants who answered the same.  Turning that one, long ago shortcoming into a strength usually doesn’t get to happen until the interview.

Comment: This has a great point - how to turn it into a positive instead of a null.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek; That *could* be true, but only if an actual human reads it and not a robot that sends applications to the automatic "circular file" for certain pre-programmed red flags.

Comment: The fact that there's a 400 letter text box suggests that, under ideal circumstances at least, it would be read by a human. It won't necessarily be someone who gives it more than a cursory skim though, so get the important facts in up front.

Comment: I would remove the Yes, and just start with Once, as a teen .... this reduces the change of a robot looking for "yes" and or someone skim reading and seeing the "yes" without changing the meaning of the answer.

Comment: -1 for suggesting that getting fired is some kind of terrible thing to have gotten yourself into - sounds like you're trying to explain away a conviction on aggravated assault or something...

Comment: @einpoklum what? Where does this answer suggest that?

Comment: @einpoklum Hasn't the company already suggested it's a negative by asking the question?  Treating it as though there is no concern runs the risk of demonstrating a fairly flippant attitude toward termination.

Comment: @JohnSpiegel: Negative, yes; but they haven't indicated what kind of negative nor how grave. It's a bit like when they ask "what would you say your worst fault is?" in this respect.

Comment: @einpoklum  I'm still not sure what the issue is with the tone of the response.  Clearly it's a form of negative.  Not addressing it leaves it as a negative.  The response is intended to indicate from that negative a positive formed.  Can you elaborate as to how it is building the negativity?

Comment: @WesSayeed  400 characters indicates human-read and Tim B's suggestion tor phrase so only a human understands is good.  I'd also recommend going to the application and seeing if there's a "powered by" or other mention of the site/software.  You may be able to research what services that company provides and whether they just make receiving applications easier or if they do filter.

Answer (score 13):

To expand on mcknz's answer.  It seems like there's mainly 2 options

- **Yes, with an attempted brief explanation**.  As you mentioned, this may immediately disqualify you.  And also as you mentioned, it's not
  like an interview where you can be personable.
- **Lie**.  As bad as it sounds, I'd consider this the best choice.  Not only because you won't get caught but simply because something
  like this from 20 years ago is just not relevant.

The choice is now up to you.  Can you morally lie on a job application?  Different people have different morals.  I would have no problem with it.

**If it makes you uncomfortable:**

1. Tell the truth
2. Explain the best that you can
3. Hope for the best.

Good luck to you :)

---

**Edit:**  A very good point came up in the comments that, I think, helps with the morality of the situation.  Employment history generally is thought of as the previous 10 years (or the most recent 7 jobs).  So it may not even be a lie to exclude such information from a job application.

Comment: Also, depends on your situation.  If you've not much in the way of cash reserves, or there's not many opportunities, then honestly ... I can see a situation where you might just "misunderstand" the question and think it just applied to jobs in your work history.  It's not as if you're using that particular job as justification as to why you should get this one.  If you can't live with yourself for that, and it's totally understandable. Where I work - being open about it would be seen as a **positive** flag about the person.  It could work in your favour

Comment: The problem with the edit to this is that the question says "have you ever...in the past".  It doesn't say "Have you ... in the last 10 years ...", or "Does your resume contain...".  The goal of the question appears to be to find out if you've *ever* been fired, because presumably it could be a red flag.  So reinterpreting the question as per the edit is questionable I think.

Comment: but @bob - "past" is relative, and infinity doesn't exist.  They don't *state* a specific time period (say, "10 years") so you have to *assume* the usual frame of interest.

Comment: I guess people can interpret that statement how they want.  Though to be fair, since a person's existence goes back finitely in time, infinity isn't an issue.  If I've been alive say 40 years, and someone asks if I've ever done X in the past, that means in my case, have I ever in the past 40 years (which is my whole life) done X.  Doesn't mean someone can't interpret it differently, just that I contend that such an interpretation would be different than the one most likely intended by the asker.

Comment: And I as one human being (others may think differently) would find an answer of "no" meaning implicitly "no not in the last 10 years" to be dishonest, or would at best think the candidate was confused. If I'm asking this question I realize people try to put their best foot forward and am trying to get around that to discover any potential red flags by asking about the candidate's *whole* employment history, not just the things they've included in their resume.

Answer (score 9):

It's very likely that, in your resume or application you surely **don't even list** your entire work history (like 25 years worth) but only the last, say, 10 years.  Is that right?

I would say with such a **minor piece of ancient history** - which is well outside your resume - it would be irrelevant.

To put in to light *just how long ago this was*, do you truly even **remember anything** about the job?

One person's name, anything?  Your desk?  The product? Where you had lunch?  Anything?

**Is it even the case** that you were literally, exactly, and legally "terminated"? Do you have any paperwork or evidence to prove that you were terminated? Were you perhaps asked to leave (was the word "terminated" even used then? People used to just get "fired" or "sacked"!) Can you even remember the full circumstances, paperwork, procedue and anything about the events?

Consider this - say for some reason someone challenged you if you were *actually* "terminated". Could you present the slightest evidence that you were literally terminated?

> Is there an acceptable expiration date on such questions?

The length of the content of your resume; 15 years anyway.

If a specific number of years is not given, you have to assume a reasonable one typical to this sort of commercial communication.

> Will I be branded a liar if I answer no?

Simply, No you will not.

You had a part-time job as a teenager and it didn't work out after a couple weeks. It would be .. grandiose .. to describe it as "terminated!"

> If I answer yes, how could I explain it succinctly, and do HR departments typically consider those explanations when screening applicants?

Unfortunately it is impossible to "explain" it in either way.

It's a yes/no item in a database.  There's no "explaining" such things.

Comment: The answer to all of your questions is yes. I remember the job, the names of my coworkers, even the address of the building, and I'm sure I still have my termination paperwork in an old box somewhere. It was not a part-time job. It was a 40-hour, full-time position that I basically pissed away. Also, I was 19.

Comment: Hey Wes - My God, that's amazing, I was drunk that entire decade  :)  Well: you can take my advice as general.  The short answer then to your question - it can only be one man's opinion - is that it's far too long ago and too minor to mention in the context. (I'd just be annoyed if I had to read something like that - you know?)  One man's take!  Good luck!!!

Comment: More to the point, is there any reason to include this job in your resume if it was 20 years ago?  Did you do anything so staggeringly original that you risk not being hired because they don't realize you're the author of the famous ---?  Then you should leave the entire job off.  There, no more need to worry about that box

Comment: @GeorgeM is it *common* practice to comment on answers without having read the question?

Comment: Incidentally, the use of *terminate* in the sense of "to dismiss from a job" dates back to at least 1973, according to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/terminate).

Comment: just as @GeorgeM says, this whole affair of a couple of weeks (from decades ago) is not even on the resume.  I have whole *careers* I don't even mention on a resume for a given field.  There has a to be a sense of proportion and realism.

Comment: It's not a yes/no question: it allows the applicant to enter 400 characters, so it appears to be looking for an explanation of some kind.

Answer (score 5):

The answer in my opinion would be no (if it's an automated system).

In person my answer would be "not in the relevant past". The point here is that the company that wants to hire you doesn't care about job experience that's 20 years ago. If job experience isn't relevant I don't see how termination is. Would you answer "yes" if you got fired from McDonald's while in high school ? That job and termination would be about as relevant to your current one as the one you did have.

One could argue that a lot of personal growth happens in 10 years, let alone 20, and especially between 18 and 38.

So yes, on an automated system I would straight up lie. If given the chance to elaborate I would.

Comment: All true! !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> On the other hand, HR departments often use this question to immediately reject potential applicants without consideration of the reasons.

Would you want to work at a company who's HR department is this judgmental and labels you for the slightest (unelaborated) answer?

The question doesn't even exclude cases of being fired due to bankrupcy, which is in no way the employee's fault. A company that dismisses anyone who answers yes to that question without asking for elaboration is not a company that values its employees, but rather sees them as numbers on a sheet (a more colloquial proverb in my culture is "meat on the pile").

---

In the end, it's best to be fully honest during job interviews, because it provides a way for you to see if the company is right for you. Job applications are a two-way street; both you and the company are looking to see if you are right for each other.

If you feel like you have to lie to get the company to consider you; then are you not always going to feel like you have to keep up a sham appearance in order to work there?
If instead you are honest from the beginning, then you know that when you get a job offer, it will be given by a company who appreciates you for who you are, rather than for who you are able to pretend to be. And in the long run, that's going to be a better workplace for you.

This is like the classic dilemma of telling a (white) lie to get a date with someone. If the date (job application) ends up going anywhere real (a job), you're studdenly stuck with the lie you told. If the date doesn't end up going anywhere (no job offer); then the lie was irrelevant since it never went further than the date (job interview) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> "Have you ever been terminated or asked to resign from a position in the past?"

Answer:

> "Yes, I got terminated from the position of `position-title-here` once, in 1998."

If they want to dig further, let them ask you about it. If they want to ask "And did it ever happen again?" - let them ask you about it. And if they want to disqualify you on these grounds - well, it might be more of a bitter pill for you to swallow, but - let them, you wouldn't want to work there anyway in this case.

Comment: I'd say the fact they are asking that is already a red flag of a highly bureaucratic inefficient establishment :)

Comment: @JuhaUntinen: Possibly, but OP does want to go work there, so let's give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I would provide some explanation as per @John Speigel's answer.  A termination in 1998 could be a minor one-time thing or a major risk indicator (e.g. it could indicate an on-going major character flaw that happened to get discovered).  It's best not to let HR's mind wander here.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen tl;dr **RUN**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, just because a company asks for some information on a form does not automatically make that information any of their business. Think race, sexual orientation, religion, etc.

Secondly, even most criminal records are deleted after 5, 10, or sometimes more years. That does not mean that you did not get convicted or sentenced, but it does mean that it is now for most intents and purposes forgiven and forgotten.

Given that your "offense" happened more than 20 years ago I believe it falls squarely in the forgiven and forgotten category.

Thus a yes-answer may be more of a lie than a no-answer in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If the exact question is “Have you ever been terminated or asked to resign from a position in the past?” then it’s not the same as “List all occasions when you were fired.”

I’m surprised none of the answers so far picked up on this. Subtle, perhaps. But an answer that’s both true and avoids the problem altogether is:

”Yes, I got laid off from my current job because of restructuring after a recent acquisition.”